# SpriteMaterial with ThreeJs | How can i set the Sprite position to stay with mesh?

Tags: three.js, position, sprite, mesh, gltf

I need to set the Sprite(Hello) position to stay with the mesh...Now, the Sprite is independent. If I rotate the object, the Sprite should stay with the mesh

LATER EDIT:
Mesh position is always 0..
[image: console screenshot]
[image: console code]

[image: Scene screenshot]

I tried for couple of hours but nothing worked..
Here is a screenshot of the code:
[image: code screenshot]

And the code...

```
    loader.load('/3D_Cars/Dacia_1410_Tuned/components/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
    carModel = gltf.scene.children[0];
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            var v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            domEvents.addEventListener(carModel.getObjectByName(child.name), 'click', function (event) {
                app.RenameAsCarParts(child.name)
                console.log(child.name)
            }, false)
            if (child.name == 'rim_RSL1_Aluminium_0') {
                child.position.set(100, 50, 3); //testing
                var spritey = makeTextSpriteNew(" Hello ",
                    { fontsize: 15, textColor: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1.0 } });
                scene.add(spritey);
            }
        }
    });

    carModel.getObjectByName('Body_paint_0').material = bodyMaterial;
    carModel.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    carModel.rotateY(Math.PI);
    scene.add(carModel);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where is this method defined makeTextSpriteNew?

You can refer this three.js example for drawing Text Sprites in three.js
https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html

The idea is, you need to provide a 3d position to this sprite so that it will project that position on screen and display the Sprite.

In your case you need to provide it the mesh's position (bounding box corner/center based on where you need to show the sprite).

```
spritey.position.set(posX, posY, posZ);
```

Comment: [makeTextSpriteNew code](https://i.postimg.cc/bYb9sVDv/Screenshot-1.png)

Comment: Mesh position is always 0.. [Console](https://i.postimg.cc/Wb0VYVDP/console.png) and [Code](https://i.postimg.cc/cLZSVzYt/console-code.png)

Comment: 3d models is [This one](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/dacia-1410-sport-tuned-9218332ab89e4a5e8700181d734296a7)